# Send live fullscreen video stream from Android device to a Linux computer

Tags: android, linux, video-editing, streaming, video-recording

I have configured [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) in my Linux Mint and I am able to stream from my computer to Facebook Live, choosing different sources (a video, any of my monitors, any image file..). However, what I want to stream from is a remote mobile device, which should just send a video from its cam which I would like to process in OBS to set some watermarks and so on and emit from OBS to Facebook Live.

I have tried Zoom for the remote device to send the video, but it's more designed for a meeting, so it adds both remote and host captures in my video. What I would like to have is a raw streaming from remote in full screen in live. Just to make it clear, the person who uses the mobile device hasn't got any knowledge about video streaming - processing.

**Note:** by "video stream" I mean literally streaming a video, not just simply "screen sharing". So the software must be capable of that (e.g. [Screen Stream](https://www.f-droid.org/en/packages/info.dvkr.screenstream/) does not suffice).

Comment: Just edited so noone else taps into the same trap – hope it's OK with you. Could you check [this list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_video_streaming) if it holds something that fits? Larix Broadcaster and CamScreen sound like they would.

Comment: Larix sounds good, but I would prefer not to have to install an RTMP with OBS all together, since OBS itself takes so many resources from my machine. Other cam solutions require you to pay to emit over mobile-data instead of WiFi. I have finally found that using [Zoom](https://zoom.us/) with fullscreen option isn't that bad.. Thanks for your help @Izzy!

Comment: Oh well… I'd rather avoid a system that had so many privacy and security issues as Zoom. But of course, it's up to you. Good luck then!